# Haskell: can Lazy Evaluation help to stop a voting earlier?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Suppose I have 10 heavy different functions (parallel or not) deciding about the same problem.
Is there a good way to implement a voting scheme that lazy-automatically realizes when a majority is reached and no more calculation is needed?

obs.: This is more a question about scope/limits of lazy ev.
Of course a simple "if" could detect a majority.

Thanks

[EDIT 1]

> ... simple "if" could detect a majority.

Sorry, I meant by "single if" -> "single wait for all process to finish".

> ... parallel or not ...

I just don't know parallelism matters in this case. (problems with my ambiguous English)

Comment: Cf [unamb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb) for functional parallelism.

Comment: It will take a while until I finish understanding everything in the answers... thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without parallel evaluation trivially, using lazy naturals. In this case I chose to use the peano-inf package on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/peano-inf

```
import Number.Peano.Inf
import Debug.Trace
import Data.List

myList = [trace "1" True, trace "2" True, trace "3" False, trace "4" True, trace "5" True]

btoNat True = 1 :: Nat
btoNat False = 0 :: Nat

ans = sum $ map btoNat myList
{-
*Main> ans > 2
1
2
3
4
True
-}
```

Note that 5 is not printed in the trace, because evaluation is cut short before then.

To do this with parallelism requires manually spawning and killing threads, etc, which is fine but certainly less pleasant.

Note that the above code uses standard sum. This sort of uncommon use-case is why, though many feel it isn't worth it, sum is not made as strict as possible.

Comment: @sclv: what if '5' finishes evaluation before 4?  This takes the first 'n' elements from your list, not the first 'n' elements to finish.

Comment: @John -- this doesn't "take" any elements from the list -- it forces enough to obtain a majority (if used with `>`). '5' won't finish evaluation before '4' because it won't *begin* to be computed until 4 is evaluated. This code is for a serial, *not* parallel answer.

Comment: Additionally, the elements can be sparked as a separate, orthogonal step, so that this _serial_ algorithm benefits from _parallel_ computation. Yay, Haskell!

Comment: @sclv - yes, that's what I meant.  However, the question specifically asks for a parallel answer.  This doesn't work at all then.

Comment: @John L: Uh, no. The question specifically asks "parallel or not". This is *precisely* in the scope of the question.

Comment: In particular, this code provides "a voting scheme that lazy-automatically realizes when a majority is reached and no more calculation is needed". It just so happens that it does so without parallel evaluation, which was specified to be in scope.

Comment: @sclv: I read the "parallel or not" as referring to the 10 different functions, not the solution.  I agree this is a reasonable serial solution.

Comment: Impressive! Stackoverflowing and learning! More about Peano numbers in Haskell:  [link](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Peano_numbers)

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer.** Yes, it is possible to implement such a system, but no, built-in laziness won't help you.

**Long answer.** I believe you need a bit different laziness. Haskell's lazy evaluation is a kind of [normal evaluation order](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-27.html#%_sec_4.2.1), which works as follows:

1. When the function is called, evaluator tries to compute it first, without computing its arguments.
2. If the control flow comes to the point, where some argument needs to be computed, it evaluates it. Then the evaluation of the function continues.

So, arguments are evaluated as needed, "on demand". Moreover, they are evaluated *one by one*. This is a good idea for the language itself, and even imperative languages with applicative order of evaluation cannot work without such lazy functions - operators like `or` and `and` are lazy by the nature in most programming languages. But in your situation, is it something you actually need? Nope. You need to evaluate all arguments in parallel and finish evaluation of function itself when some of args are computed.

**How to implement.** You need to completely re-implement evaluation system, and I believe pure functional programming without side-effects and lazy evaluation will only hinder you. Here's one way to do it. Create function, say, `paplly :: [ArgumentType] -> TriggerFunction -> ResultType`, where `papply` stands for "parallel apply", `ArgumentType` is a type of actual arguments to compute (in your case it may be closure of function + problem to solve), `TriggerFunction` is a function, which is called when one of args is computed, and `ResultType` is Boolean in your case. This function must work as follows:

1. Run evaluation of all arguments in parallel.
2. When one of arguments is computed, it must call the TriggerFunction with the result of evaluation.
3. The trigger function must have a "memory" to remember all previous results. If, when called, it founds out, that there are enough arguments to finish evaluation of main function, it does it, interrupting computing the rest of args.

This is only one of the ways to do it, not the most functional (it uses mutable "memory"). You can also run the trigger function in parallel with other arguments and use some kind of synchronization to pass control between all of them. Or you can use some kind of messages like in Erlang or Scala. Unfortunately I haven't enough experience with Haskell to write actual code, but @Dietrich Epp's post seems to represent similar idea, so you can use it as a base.

Answer (score 3):

You want a function like this:

```
majority :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

And you want it to work in parallel.  No sweat!  Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to do this without bypassing the type system.  Here is an example implementation:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.IO.Unsafe

majority :: [Bool] -> Bool
majority votes = unsafePerformIO $
  do v <- newEmptyMVar
     nfalse <- newMVar 0
     ntrue <- newMVar 0
     let n = length votes
         m = (n `div` 2) + 1
         count x =
           let (var, min) = if x then (ntrue, m) else (nfalse, n-m+1)
           in do i <- modifyMVar var $ \i -> return (i+1, i+1)
                 if i == min then putMVar v x else return ()
     threads <- mapM (forkIO . count) votes
     r <- takeMVar v
     mapM_ killThread threads
     return r
```

Note: I'm not positive this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried combining the sclv's solution with luqui's comment about `unamb` and would like to share my results. I'll start with the test cases:

```
list1 = [True, True, undefined, True, undefined]
list2 = [undefined, False, False]
list3 = concat $ replicate 500 list1
list4 = concat $ replicate 500 list2


main = mapM (print . vote) [list1, list2, list3, list4]

vote :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

This should print

```
True
False
True
False
```

I'll start with the `list1` example first. The voting function to pass it can look like this:

```
voteByTrue list = sum (map bToNat list) >= threshold
  where
    threshold = (genericLength list + 1) `quot` 2
```

This is the same as in sclv's answer. Now we need to make `sum` lazier so that the computation does not abort upon encountering an `undefined` summand. My first take on this was:

```
Zero |+ y = y
Succ x |+ y = Succ (x + y)

instance Num Nat where
    x + y = (x |+ y) `lub` (y |+ x)
```

Here, `|+` is the addition operator strict in its first argument and `+` is non-strict in both of its arguments. It worked for toy examples, like `list1`, but the performance of this solution deteriorates very quickly because of the exponential blow-up of the number of threads (see how each `+` spawns 2 threads, each of which calls `+` again, usually with the same arguments). With such performance, `vote list3` does not terminate quickly enough. To fight this, I have tried violating the `unamb`'s contract and implemented the following function:

```
-- | The same as unamb, but does not have the 
--   'agree unless bottom' precondition.
brokenUnamb = unamb

infoMinMax a b = (x, y) 
  where
    ~(x, y) = (a `seq` (b, a)) `brokenUnamb` (b `seq` (a, b))
```

This function sorts its two arguments by the amount of information they hold. It always returns less evaluated value as the `x` and more evaluated value as the `y`. This breaks purity by violating the condition of `unamb` arguments to be equal. However, it allows us to implement `+` more efficiently:

```
instance Num Nat where
    x + y = x' |+ y' where (y', x') = infoMinMax x y
```

This allows us to pass the large test (`list3`)! Now, to the false-tests... It turned out that `infoMinMax` function is useful here as well!

```
vote list = voteByTrue list `maxInfo` voteByFalse list
  where
    voteByFalse = not . voteByTrue . map not
    maxInfo x y = snd (infoMinMax x y)
```

Now, this allows the program to pass all four tests, albeit the large ones take several seconds to complete. The CPU usage skyrockets to 200% if I replace `undefined` with `odd (sum [1..])` too, so some parallelism is indeed happening.

However, the problem of broken purity remains. Can someone suggest a solution where simple `unamb` is enough?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems that the more I learn Haskell, the harder it becomes.

Comment: @davips, well, to be fair, impurity introduced by `unamb` makes it not-strictly-a-Haskell. If you are confused by how Haskell's laziness works, I was there too, but it became much better when I realised that there is no magic there, the rule is simple -- Haskell does not evaluate anything unless required to.

Answer (score -1):

if we consider that those functions yield booleans, the question becomes if it is possible to write a function that takes 10 booleans and returns true if 6 of them are true that always requires the values of fewer than 10 of its inputs.

the simple way but one that doesn't fit the stated requirements is to test each input in turn counting up the number of trues and falses if trues >= 6 stop return true else if falses >= 6 stop return false and if we reach the last input without triggering either of those conditions, return false. as this will test all the inputs in some cases, so i think the answer to this question is no, lazy evaluation doesn't help in this example.